# Error calculating MAC on Thales Payshield 9000 HSM

Tags: hsm

I've a strange problem with M6 command in HSM Payshield 9000 3.4C firmware. For some leghts of message I receive error code 15 - even if message length is multiply of 8 bytes.

During call I'm sending:
1. Mode Flag: 0
2. Input Format Flag: 0
3. MAC Size: 1
4. MAC Algo: 3
5. Padding Method: 0 (I tested also with 0, 1, 3, but to simplify lets focus on padding mode 0. For test I prepared byte arrays to be mac'ed which size is multiply of 8 so no padding is needed).
6. Key type: 008

I created a simple test where in a loop I'm building byte arrays of '1' with size from 8 to 1000 and mac such array. Each array has length that is multiply of 8 (8,16,24, ...)

For some of array leghts I receive error code 15 Invalid input data (invalid format, invalid characters, or not enough data provided). Below you can find array size ranges for which I'm receiving such error. (<160-248> means I received error for array of length from 160 (included) to 248(included) which are multiple of 8 (160, 168, 176,....248)

<160 - 248>
<416 - 504>
<672 - 760>
<928 - 1000>

For other all other sizes from that range (for example from 256-408 that are multiple of 8 I'm receiving correct response with calculated MAC

For byte array of lengh 160 (which returns error) the example command that I'm sending in this test is (in hex format):

```
00d33f3f3f3f4d3630303133303030385544324241464236353835433642303735334334363645393434424338423837353030613031313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131
```

Example command (for array of 152 size) which returns correct response:

```
00cb3f3f3f3f4d363030313330303038554432424146423635383543364230373533433436364539343442433842383735303039383131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131313131
```

What can be the reason of such behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it. The problem was in the message length tag. When the message length represented as 4 digit Hex contains letters, they should be sent in uppercase, ie. 00A0 instead of 00a0